# Configurable products price text not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

Running: Magento 1.9.1.0 Community

Not sure if this is a common problem I just don't know the answer to or not, In my prices.phtml (template/catalog/product/price.phtml) has the word "RRP" and "Price" next to the original price and the special price set in magento admin panel. This works fine until it comes to a simple configurable product which then makes the text before the prices vanish (Shows up for a brief second then loads and removes the text RRP and Price).

Here is my prices.phtml from RWD:
http://pastebin.com/M7zivZmy

Top example is a simple product, bottom is simple configurable:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/xCgXsKf.png]

Does Magento pull the prices for configurable products from a different template? Or would there be a reason its removing the text on load?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you clear the cache? Because I tried your code and succeed.
Here the code I tested : [Pastebin : Magento Stackexchange Question 74109 : price.phtml](http://pastebin.com/ERDiHHwk)

And here the capture (above is configurable product and below is simple product) :

[image: Price]

Just a suggestion, it's best to write your code

```
<?php echo "RRP:";?>
<?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_regularPrice + $_originalWeeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
```

become

```
<?php echo "RRP:".$_coreHelper->formatPrice($_regularPrice + $_originalWeeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
```

the same thing if you want to add text Price

```
<?php echo "Price ".$_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
```